# Google Cloud SQL monitoring

Tags: mysql, monitoring, google-cloud-sql

I am wondering what are the current/existing possibilities of monitoring mysql instances on Google Cloud SQL? What I need is:

- define alerts and trigger actions (send via http) for set of mysql metrics
- retrive metrics via http

There is not much I see in Google Cloud SQL dashboard for my mysql instance. When I go to **Monitoring -> Dashboard & alerts** I see that it is disabled due to **Stackdriver** migration. Am I doing something wrong here or what I want/looking for is not possible at the moment?

Answer (score 1):

Although the dashboard & alerts are not yet available, there is an API to access monitoring statistics: [Cloud Monitoring](https://developers.google.com/cloud-monitoring/). You would need to build your own alerting/trigger system on top of this at the moment.